# UI not updating when it should

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observableArray of locations in my view model.

1. I create the checkbox list using locations array.
2. I also display the checked locations in UI using locations array.

When the checkbox is checked, the view model gets updated. However, the displayed locations does not updated.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
    <li data-bind="text: name, visible: checked"></li>
</ul>

<ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id, checked: checked" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span><br/>
    </li>
</ul>
<br/>
<button data-bind="click: debug">Debug</button>
```

```
var locations = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'PP', 'checked': false},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Ta keo', 'checked': false},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Kompong Som', 'checked': true}
];

var viewModel;

viewModel = (function() {
    function viewModel(locations) {
        self = this;
        this.locations = ko.observableArray(locations);
        this.debug = function() {
          alert(JSON.stringify(self.locations()));  
        };
    }
    return viewModel;
})();

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(locations));
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bL7weqkz/

Answer (score 1):

Your `checked` property of `locations` variable needs to be observable, so `knockout.js` could detect when the property updated. Change your code to this:

```
var locations = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'PP', 'checked': ko.observable(false)},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Ta keo', 'checked': ko.observable(false)},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Kompong Som', 'checked': ko.observable(true)}
];
```

Comment: Though, it would be more appropriate to make them observable when they are mapped into the view model.